# Multiple propositions for multiple class prediction

Tags: keras, lstm

I am working on a word prediction problem. I have examples of career path, and I would like to be able to predict a next person's job using their last 2 jobs.  I have built a LSTM model to perform it

I have a problem when intenting to get multiple results from keras `model.predict_classes` function. It only returns 1 result. I would like to get multiple results, ordered by their probability.

Here is the code :

```py
from numpy import array
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Embedding

# generate a sequence from a language model
def generate_seq(model, tokenizer, max_length, seed_text, n_words):
    in_text = seed_text
    # generate a fixed number of words
    for _ in range(n_words):
        # encode the text as integer
        encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([in_text])[0]
        # pre-pad sequences to a fixed length
        encoded = pad_sequences([encoded], maxlen=max_length, padding='pre')
        # predict probabilities for each word
        yhat = model.predict_classes(encoded, verbose=1)
        print('yhat = ' + yhat)
        #print('yhat : ' + str(yhat))
        # map predicted word index to word
        out_word = ''
        for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
            if index == yhat:
                out_word = word
                break
        # append to input
        in_text += ' ' + out_word
    return in_text


# source text
data = """apprenti electricien chefOdeOprojet \n
soudeur chefOdeOsection directeurOusine\n
mecanicien chefOdeOsection directeurOadjoint\n
ingenieur chefOdeOprojet directeurOadjoint directeurOusine\n
ingenieur chefOdeOprojet \n
apprenti soudeur chefOdeOsection chefOdeOprojet\n
ingenieurOetude chefOdeOprojet\n
ingenieurOetude manager chefOdeOprojet directeurOdepartement\n
apprenti gestionOproduction manager directeurOdepartement\n
ingenieurOetude commercial\n
soudeur ingenieurOetude manager directeurOadjoint\n
ingenieurOetude directeurOdepartement directeurOusine\n
apprenti soudeur\n
agentOsecurite chefOsecurite\n
apprenti mecanicien ouvrier manager\n
commercial directeurOadjoint\n
agentOsecurite chefOsecurite\n
directeurOusine retraite\n
ouvrier manager\n
ingenieur vente\n
secretaire comptable\n
comptable chefOcomptable\n
chefOcomptable directeurOdepartement\n
assistant secretaire comptable\n
assistant comptable\n
assistant secretaire commercial\n
commercial chefOdeOprojet\n
commercial vente chefOdeOprojet\n
electricien chefOdeOsection\n
apprenti ouvrier chefOdeOsection\n"""
# integer encode sequences of words
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([data])
encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([data])[0]
# retrieve vocabulary size
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
print('Vocabulary Size: %d' % vocab_size)
# encode 2 words -> 1 word    
sequences = list()
for line in data.split('\n'):
    encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([line])[0]
    for i in range(2, len(encoded)):
        sequence = encoded[i-2:i+1]
        sequences.append(sequence)    

print('Total Sequences: %d' % len(sequences))
# pad sequences
max_length = max([len(seq) for seq in sequences])
sequences = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding='pre')
print('Max Sequence Length: %d' % max_length)
# split into input and output elements
sequences = array(sequences)
X, y = sequences[:,:-1],sequences[:,-1]
y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 10, input_length=max_length-1))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(Dense(units = 3,  activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
# compile network
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
model.fit(X, y, epochs=500, verbose=0)
# evaluate model
print(generate_seq(model, tokenizer, max_length-1, 'electricien secretaire', 1))
```

and there is the console display:

```
Vocabulary Size: 24
Total Sequences: 20
Max Sequence Length: 3
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (None, 2, 10)             240       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 50)                12200     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 24)                1224      
=================================================================
Total params: 13,664
Trainable params: 13,664
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 86ms/step
yhat = [1]
electricien secretaire chefodeoprojet
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to see the probabilities associated with each class of a multi-classification problem?

The code looks pretty correct to me, but I would recommend trying a different evaluation step. I have gotten multi-classifier outputs with the following snippet:

```py
 # Fit the model
    print "Fitting model..."
    model.fit(np.asarray(self.X), np.asarray(self.Y), epochs=200, batch_size=10)
    print "Model fitting complete."

    self.TEST = np.asarray(self.TEST).reshape(( test_data.shape[0], 1, 128))
    print "Predicting on Test (unseen) data..."
    predictions = model.predict(self.TEST)

    # Sigmoid predictions
    labels = np.zeros(predictions.shape)
    labels[predictions>0.5] = 1
    print "Prediction labels for unseen: " + str(labels)
```

The output:

```
 Prediction labels for unseen: 
 [[ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

Each row denotes the classification of one sample; the index of the 1 represents which class (A,B,C,D) the sample fell into.